# Issue uploading multiple images to a page with "upload" button...

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a **[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/457fd/)**...

I've accomplished the ability to get an image to load below the upload button, however, how can I upload multiple images to the same page? There are three places where I've allowed the user to upload a specific image.

```
<div class="element-file" title="Do you want to add an image to the Accreditation Text?">
    <label class="title" style="font-weight: bold;">Add an image to the left of the Accreditation text<br>(Image will be resized to 100px by 100px)</label>

    <label class="medium" >
            <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    </label>
        <p><strong>(Image will display below)</strong></p>
            <div style="max-width: 100px; height: auto; border:1px dashed black;">
                <img id="accred_image" src="accred" alt="" />
            </div>
</div>
```

**And add an image to this area...**

```
<div class="element-file" title="Do you want to add an image to the Accreditation Text?">
    <label class="title" style="font-weight: bold;">Would you like to add a logo image?</label>

    <label class="medium" >
            <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    </label>
        <p><strong>(Image will display below)</strong></p>
                <div style="max-width: 140px; height: auto; border:1px dashed black;">
                    <img id="blah" src="" alt="" />
                </div>
</div>
```

**This is my javascript, but when I upload an image, it places the same image in both spots. I thought this had something to do with the class I am uploading from, but creating the new class, doesn't seem to help at all.**

```
$("input").change(function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
             $('#accred_image').attr('src', reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find that is the img to update.
Try this:

```
$("input").change(function(e) {

    var elemIMG = $(this).parent().parent().find('img'); // find the img to update

    for (var i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.srcElement.files.length; i++) {

        var file = e.originalEvent.srcElement.files[i];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
              elemIMG.attr('src',reader.result); // update the img src
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);        }
});
```